# How to select the context in a page using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a static webpage with text/sentences inside `<p>` paragraph Tag. Please help me on how to select the text in the paragraph using Selenium webDriver.

Note: I don't want to highlight the elements.

Comment: What do you mean by "select", do you mean obtain the text content?

Comment: Yes @Amey I mean the text content

Comment: Just like we do [Ctrl + A] but I want specific content paragraph to be selected

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose?

Comment: I need this for a demo